# Difference in numpy and sympy lambdify results for basic optimization

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, sympy, mathematical-optimization

I wrote following code for basic optimization based on Newton's method by writing derivatives explicitly and by calculating them using sympy. Why are the results different?

Writing derivatives explicitly:

```
import numpy as np
def g(x):
    return 1.95 - np.exp(-2/x) - 2*np.exp(-np.power(x,4))
# gd: Derivative of g

def gd(x):
    return -2*np.power(x,-2)*np.exp(-2/x) + 8*np.power(x,3)*np.exp(-np.power(x,4))

def gdd(x):
return -4*np.power(x,-3)*np.exp(-2/x)-4*np.power(x,-4)*np.exp(-2/x)+24*np.power(x,2)*np.exp(-np.power(x,4))-32*np.power(x,6)*np.exp(-np.power(x,4))

# Newton's
def newton_update(x0,g,gd):
    return x0 - g(x0)/gd(x0)
# Main func
x0 = 1.00
condition = True
loops = 1
max_iter = 20
while condition and loops<max_iter:   
    x1 = newton_update(x0,gd,gdd)
    loops += 1
    condition = np.abs(x0-x1) >= 0.001 
    x0 = x1
    print('x =',x0)


if loops == max_iter:
    print('Solution failed to converge. Try another starting value!')
```

Output:

```
x = 1.66382322329
x = 1.38056881356
x = 1.43948432592
x = 1.46207570893
x = 1.46847791968
x = 1.46995571549
x = 1.47027303095
```

Using sympy and lambdify:

```
import sympy as sp
x = sp.symbols('x',real=True)
f_expr = 1.95 - exp(-2/x) - 2*exp(-x**4)
dfdx_expr = sp.diff(f_expr, x)
ddfdx_expr = sp.diff(dfdx_expr, x)

# lambidify
f = sp.lambdify([x],f_expr,"numpy")
dfdx = sp.lambdify([x], dfdx_expr,"numpy")
ddfdx = sp.lambdify([x], ddfdx_expr,"numpy")

# Newton's
x0 = 1.0
condition = True
loops = 1
max_iter = 20
while condition and loops<max_iter:   
    x1 = newton_update(x0,dfdx,ddfdx)
    loops += 1
    condition = np.abs(x0-x1) >= 0.001 
    x0 = x1
    print('x =',x0)


if loops == max_iter:
    print('Solution failed to converge. Try another starting value!')
```

Output:

```
x = 1.90803013971
x = 3.96640484492
x = 6.6181614689
x = 10.5162392894
x = 16.3269006983
x = 25.0229734288
x = 38.0552735534
x = 57.5964036862
x = 86.9034400129
x = 130.860980508
x = 196.795321033
x = 295.695535237
x = 444.044999522
x = 666.568627836
x = 1000.35369299
x = 1501.03103981
x = 2252.04689304
x = 3378.57056168
x = 5068.35599056
Solution failed to converge. Try another starting value!
```

I made it to work by step halving in newton_update function whenever sign of derivative changes in the update. But I couldn't figure out why the results were so different with the same starting point. Also is it possible to get the same results from both?

Answer (score 1):

There is a mistake in the second derivative formula in the function gdd. changing

```
def gdd(x):
     return -4*np.power(x,-3)*np.exp(-2/x)-4*np.power(x,-4)*np.exp(-2/x)+24*np.power(x,2)*np.exp(-np.power(x,4))-32*np.power(x,6)*np.exp(-np.power(x,4))
```

to

```
def gdd(x):
    return 4*np.power(x,-3)*np.exp(-2/x)-4*np.power(x,-4)*np.exp(-2/x)+24*np.power(x,2)*np.exp(-np.power(x,4))-32*np.power(x,6)*np.exp(-np.power(x,4))
```

should resolve the issue and produce the same result in both cases, which will be

```
x = 1.90803013971
x = 3.96640484492
x = 6.6181614689
x = 10.5162392894
x = 16.3269006983
x = 25.0229734288
x = 38.0552735534
x = 57.5964036862
x = 86.9034400129
x = 130.860980508
x = 196.795321033
x = 295.695535237
x = 444.044999522
x = 666.568627836
x = 1000.35369299
x = 1501.03103981
x = 2252.04689304
x = 3378.57056168
x = 5068.35599056
Solution failed to converge. Try another starting value!
```

This points to a problem with choosing the step size as per the comment